# Linear regression model with a known parameter

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

**Question:**

Consider the following linear regression with one parameter (intercept $\beta_{0}$ known).

$ y_{i} = \beta_{0}^{*} + \beta_{1}x_{i} + \epsilon_{i} $ for i = 1,....n

a) Compute the **LSE , MLE , mean and varience** for $\beta_{1}$.

I understand how to derive the following when both the slope and intercept is unknown. However I'm unsure what the effect of knowing what the intercept will have on the new computations.

Attempt: We minimsise the LSE by setting

$\partial_{\beta_{1}} S(\beta_{1}) = - \sum_{i=1}^{n} 2x_{i}(y_{i}-\beta_{0}^{*}-\beta_{1}x_{i}) = 0 $

After long computations we get

$\beta_{1} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} (y_{i} - \beta_{0}^{*})   }{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}^2)}$

The computation of the least square estimator doesn't seem to care wether $b_{0}$ is known or unknown so would be get the same LSE,MLE,mean and variance as with the case $b_{0}$ is unknown

Answer (score 1):

Since $\beta _{\,0} ^ * $ is determined, we have better and consider
$$
z_{\,i}  = y_{\,i}  - \beta _{\,0} ^ *  
$$

Then the error squared is
$$
E^{\,2} (\beta _{\,1} ) = \sum\limits_i {\left( {z_{\,i}  - \beta _{\,1} x_{\,i} } \right)^{\,2} } 
$$
and it gets minimized when
$$
\eqalign{
  & {d \over {d\beta _{\,1} }}E^{\,2} (\beta _{\,1} ) = 0\quad  \to \quad \sum\limits_i {x_{\,i} \left( {z_{\,i}  - \beta _{\,1} x_{\,i} } \right)}  = 0\quad  \to   \cr 
  &  \to \quad \beta _{\,1}  = {{\sum\limits_i {x_{\,i} z_{\,i} } } \over {\sum\limits_i {x_{\,i} ^2 } }} \cr} 
$$

This is similar to what you got, except that the denominator
involves the raw second moment of the $x_i$.

Thereafter, *to analize the reliability (possible error) on the estimated parameter $\beta _{\,1}$* we proceed as follows.

Suppose that the true line is 
$$
\hat z = \hat \beta _{\,1} x
$$
and, since the $x_i$ are considered "precise", the $z_i$ be subject instead to deviation wrt to the true value $ \hat z_{\,i}$
$$
z_{\,i}  = \hat z_{\,i}  + \varepsilon _{\,i}  = \hat \beta _{\,1} x_{\,i}  + \varepsilon _{\,i} 
$$
then
$$
\eqalign{
  & \beta _{\,1}  = {1 \over {\sum\limits_i {x_{\,i} ^2 } }}\sum\limits_i {x_{\,i} z_{\,i} }
  = {1 \over {\sum\limits_i {x_{\,i} ^2 } }}\sum\limits_i {x_{\,i} \left( {\hat \beta _{\,1} x_{\,i}  + \varepsilon _{\,i} } \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \hat \beta _{\,1}  + \sum\limits_i {{{x_{\,i} } \over {\sum\limits_i {x_{\,i} ^2 } }}\varepsilon _{\,i} }  \cr} 
$$
so the error of $beta_1$ is a linear combination of the errors in $z$.

Therefore, assuming that the intercept  $\beta _{\,0} ^ * $ was precise, we can assume
that the $\varepsilon _{\,i} $ be random variables with null mean. And if they are i.i.d., the variance of $\beta_1-\hat \beta _{\,1} $ follows easily.

In particular, 
$$
z_{\,i}  = \hat z_{\,i}  + \varepsilon _{\,i}  = \hat \beta _{\,1} x_{\,i}  + \varepsilon _{\,i} \quad  \to \quad E\left[ {z_{\,i} } \right] = \hat \beta _{\,1} E\left[ {x_{\,i} } \right] + E\left[ {\varepsilon _{\,i} } \right]
$$
and if the $\varepsilon _{\,i} $ have null mean then, introducing the sample averages indicated with the over bar, we shall have
$$
\bar z_{\,i}  \approx \hat \beta _{\,1} \bar x_{\,i}  \approx \beta _{\,1} \bar x_{\,i} 
$$
which means that the line shall pass (almost) through the barycenter of the cloud of points.
That is the case in fact, when you compute the regression line with two parameters.  Practically you do that by shifting the origin of the coordinates at the barycenter and
then computing the slope as above, now using the central moments.

If instead the $ \varepsilon _{\,i} $ actually have a mean non null
$$
\hat z = \hat \beta _{\,1} x + \hat \mu \quad \quad z_{\,i}  = \hat z_{\,i}  + \varepsilon _{\,i}  = \hat \beta _{\,1} x_{\,i}  + \hat \mu  + \varepsilon _{\,i} 
$$
then in the calculation above we are introducing an error
$$
\eqalign{
  & \beta _{\,1}  = {1 \over {\sum\limits_i {x_{\,i} ^2 } }}\sum\limits_i {x_{\,i} z_{\,i} }  = {1 \over {\sum\limits_i {x_{\,i} ^2 } }}\sum\limits_i {x_{\,i} \left( {\hat \beta _{\,1} x_{\,i}
  + \varepsilon _{\,i}  + \hat \mu } \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {\hat \beta _{\,1}  + \hat \mu {{\sum\limits_i {x_{\,i} } } \over {\sum\limits_i {x_{\,i} ^2 } }}} \right) + \sum\limits_i {{{x_{\,i} } \over {\sum\limits_i {x_{\,i} ^2 } }}\varepsilon _{\,i} }  \cr} 
$$

Comment: Not too sure here about some of the notation, is $\beta$ your estimator , $\hat{\beta}$ your parameter and $z_{i} = \beta_{1}x_{i}$ with $\bar{z} = \beta_{1}\bar{x}$

Comment: @Swag34214: the hat denotes the supposedly "true" value, the overbar the average

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually still confused the notations and overall general proof. What is your derived LSE? Why does your estimate rely on the parameter when its unknown??

Comment: @Swag34214: I recasted my answer trying to make better clear the concepts. In particular note that the first part is the LSE computation, the second is about the reliability of the results obtained. Also note that regression - explicitly or implicitly - always relies on a "supposedly true" generating model which is what is to be estimated leveling out the superimposed  "noise".

Comment: Okay thanks I think I had a similar result which I have editted into the question. $\beta_{1} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} (y_{i} - \beta_{0}^{*})   }{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}^2)}$ , do we just leave it like that since $\beta_{0}^{*}$ is known.

Comment: I get it now, appreciate the help. I've computed the mean and variance of our new estimator and believe it is biased $\frac{1}{n}\beta_{1}$. Just want clarification if im on the right track here.

Comment: @Swag34214: .."probably" yes, you should be on the right track, but cannot tell without knowing the data.  Just make the above and a 2 parameters LSE and compare the results.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Do exactly what is done with the two parameters $\beta_0,\beta_1$ but with only $\beta_1$ as a parameter. For example, it means that the partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_1}$ is in fact a usual derivative depending of $x_i, y_i$ and $\beta_0$ which is supposed to be known.

Comment: I seem to get the same LSE,MLE,mean and variance as with 2 unknowns. I don't think its correct however.